# Export a web project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

i have made a web application using java pages with eclipse.

But i have no idea how to export it for use?

I was asked to provide a make file or somehting, what other ways can i do this from eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you need to export it as a WAR file:

- Right-click the project in Eclipse
- Choose `Export`
- Choose `WAR File`

  [image: screenshot]

Comment: Oh cool thanks, and will they have to manually set up the mysql database?

Comment: I would imagine so... databases don't magically set themselves up.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the project and say export war.

There choose the appropriate server runtime for which you have created the project.

Then put that war file inside the webapps folder in case apache tomcat and restart the server.

And you have done. :)