# How to make webDriver testsuite created in windows machine to run in a linux box

Tags: linux, selenium-webdriver, executable-jar

I have got selenium `WebDriver` testsuite done using TestNg framework. I have used selenium webDriver 2.44.0 & FF32.

Now my build team wants my test to run in their demo box which is linux machine.  10.**.***.248 box

What i have done till now. I am not using any other tools like jenkis, maven etc.

1. Created  java project 'myproject' testsuite in ecplise luna using
   TestNg frame in my windows machine
2. Created a runnable Jar for myproject( myproject-version-1.0.1.jar)
3. Placed the runnable jar in 248 box using winSCP in a folder /home/project/
4. In 248 machine FF37 is available. So i upgraded my script with selenium 2.45.0 . It runs fine in my windows machine with FF32 version also.
5. Now using putty i logged into 248 machine and reached the folder /home/project/ where my runnable jar is placed.
6. I executed the shell command *java -jar myproject-version-1.0.1.jar*

Console shows the following exception:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  Command line suite
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified
```

I know i have not done correctly. I read few links posted here about about setting display in linux machine , using  Xvfb – the X Virtual FrameBuffer. 
[Webdriver Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms)

I think the person who posted the question in above link had done the similar settings. !

Can somebody please help me with this as i am not able to understand :( Step by step process so that i can run my script in build team's machine.

I am very new to this field and doing all this for the first time. I read someting about headless GUI etc. I am not able to understand.

Would really appreciate if you could help me understand the steps involved.

Comment: Build is using Red Hat based system.

Comment: How your test Suite is designed? Can you post the method that is opening firefox browser?

Comment: Hi Aura , below is my code to set up the firefox. This works fine for my windows machine

@BeforeTest
 public  void setUp()
 {
   WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.get("http://docs.seleniumhq.org/");
 }

Answer (score 0):

You have done pretty much the right things as specified in the question

One thing that I came to observer that you have not specified complete URL in the get method. This might cause you some trouble. So first edit

```
driver.get("docs.seleniumhq.org/");
```

to

```
driver.get("http://docs.seleniumhq.org/");
```

If the code  still doesn't works. Then try bundling latest selenium-java.jar and selenium-standalone.jar

But from the error it also seems that may be port 7055 is not free. (but I think you already checked that.)

So the problem gets a little bit confined to the selenium jars which are often incompatible if they are of different versions.

Comment: Hi aura. Thank u for your response. driver.get("URL ") i have given the complete llink only . till it doesnt work. I strongly feel its bcos of headless GUI. Maybe my script is not able to find the browser in that 248 linux machine. 
in 248 machine... command line .. i gave the command firefox -v  so  could see Morzilla Firefox 37.0.1. So firefox is there in the machine rt? i am using selenium 2.45.0. But as u mentioned what is the need of selenium.standalone ? as i m using webDriver

Comment: I was successfully able to reproduce the situation. Try to login on your linux machine with the command "ssh -X user@ip". If possible try it with some other linux machine instead of using putty. In my case the browser opened.

Comment: HI Aura, i seriously need help. I am still facing the same issue. Running my jar file in linux machine 10.**.***.248 using a putty. this 248 machine has firefox installed. When i run the jar file in my command prompt in my windows machine the code runs fine. But in linux m/c still shows the same error
[TestNG] Running:
  Command line suite
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified

Comment: So i do feel its because its not getting a proper GUI ?? cos then how can it run fine in Command prompt in windows m/c and not in linux m/c

Comment: older versions of putty might create this problem thats why i asked if you can try ssh with a linux machine. Did you tried what I mentioned above?